# Angular 2 in Phonegap doesn't work (plain javascript)

Tags: javascript, cordova, angular

I build a website with angular 2 in plain javascript and everything it's working ok in browser, but when I try to build phonegapp app or use it with Phonegap Mobile app it doesn't work.

In index.html I have:

```
<body>
        <app>Loading app...</app>



        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
        <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.3/Rx.umd.js"></script>
        <script src="libs/angular/2.0.0-beta.3/angular2-all.umd.js"></script>


        <!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
        <script src='app/services.build.js'></script>        <!-- All our services, as server comunication -->
        <script src='app/components.build.js'></script>      <!-- All the components -->
        <script src='app/app.component.js'></script>            <!-- App component, main one -->
        <script src='app/main.js'></script>                     <!-- Main -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            phonegapApp.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
```

And on main.js I have:

```
var phonegapApp = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(AppComponent,[
            ng.router.ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
            new ng.core.Provider(ng.router.LocationStrategy, {useClass: ng.router.HashLocationStrategy})
        ]);
    }
};
```

So I include `ng.platform.browser.bootstrap` when device is ready. (Also tried with `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...}` but with same result.

All that I can see it's Loading... so `<app>Loading...</app>` it's not interpreted by angular.

Do you have any idea what I should change to work? Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to add references of `es-5-shim` here to support it on phonegap.

Comment: Did you check that the `onDeviceReady` method is called?

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks for the tip. It worked adding es6-shim.min.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `shims` to make it working on `phonegap`. That can be either `es6-shim.js`/`es5-shim.js`

Probably that will solve your issue.