# Phonegap - Angular2 app doesn't load in mobile

Tags: cordova, angular, phonegap-cli

I have created Angular2+Typescript web application. It works fine in browser. After converting this web app to mobile app (android) using Phonegap, it render only static HTML. It doesn't load any angular2 component or functionality neither throws any error on screen.

Here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!--<base href="/">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <title>My Goal Tracker</title>

    <!-- CSS  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        phonegapApp.initialize();
    </script>


    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.35.0/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2@2.0.0-beta.12/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/typescript@1.8.9/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.12/router.dev.js"></script>



    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
        System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <home>Loading...</home>

    <footer class="page-footer orange">
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <div class="container">
                Made by <a class="orange-text text-lighten-3" href="http://uvbrain.com">UVBrain Solutions</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--  Scripts-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Phonegap project structure is as below:
[image]

Could anybody please let me know what could be the issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [see this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436047/angular-2-in-phonegap-doesnt-work-plain-javascript)

Comment: @Chavan are you really using both *Phongap Build* and *Phonegap CLI*. This is not normal. There are three (3) different systems for Corodova/Phonegap [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001). Which are you using?

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, I have created blank application using Phonegap Desktop application. Then in www folder I put my angular2 website code. After that I ran phonegap serve command and tested on my mobile.

Comment: Okay. You are not using *Phonegap Build*. You are using *Phonegap CLI*

Answer (score -3, accepted):

After putting debug logs and alerts, I found the issue. It was with routing mechanism of ng2 which was causing issue.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this as an answer, please provide one.