# Angular in Plain JavaScript on IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11, office-js

I need to use Angular 4+ in plain JavaScript on IE11. My overall application is an [OfficeJS add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/), that is using the [Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) to open a new window (IE11) from my add-in. There are several constraints:

- Must run on IE11.
- Must use plain JavaScript (I cannot use TypeScript).
- Runs in its own context. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-the-office-dialog-api-with-single-page-applications-and-client-side-routing)
- Must be as lightweight as possible (so I cannot have it reinitialize / bootstrap my entire Angular app again. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#use-the-office-dialog-api-with-single-page-applications-and-client-side-routing)). Think of the dialog as its own mini-app.

I have [tried](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/05/09/writing-angular-2-code-in-es5.html) [following](https://daveceddia.com/angular-2-in-plain-js/) [these](http://nicholasjohnson.com/blog/how-to-do-everything-in-angular2-using-es6/) [great](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43868701/how-to-use-angular-2-or-4-framework-from-cdn) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35436047/angular-2-in-phonegap-doesnt-work-plain-javascript), but was unable to get Angular to boot up.

[My plunker is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3WLURdoF9gzgsrQBTdP?p=preview).

The errors I get on IE11 are:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'Class' (app.component.js (7,3))
Object doesn't support property or method 'Class' (app.module.js (7,3))
No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'. (compiler.umd.min.js (55,26076))
```

On Chrome (when looking at the Plunker) I get these errors:

```
app.component.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Component(...).Class is not a function
    at window.app.window.app (VM524 app.component.js:11)
    at VM524 app.component.js:15
window.app.window.app @ app.component.js:11
(anonymous) @ app.component.js:15
app.module.js:13 Uncaught TypeError: NgModule(...).Class is not a function
    at window.app.window.app (VM525 app.module.js:13)
    at VM525 app.module.js:16
window.app.window.app @ app.module.js:13
(anonymous) @ app.module.js:16
compiler.umd.min.js:sourcemap:55 Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'undefined'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (VM475 compiler.umd.min.js:55)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (VM475 compiler.umd.min.js:53)
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (VM475 compiler.umd.min.js:62)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (VM475 compiler.umd.min.js:62)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (VM475 compiler.umd.min.js:62)
    at CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (VM476 platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js:6)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (VM472 core.umd.min.js:113)
    at window.app.window.app ((index):42)
    at (index):44
NgModuleResolver.resolve @ compiler.umd.min.js:sourcemap:55
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.umd.min.js:sourcemap:53
JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.umd.min.js:sourcemap:62
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.umd.min.js:sourcemap:62
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.umd.min.js:sourcemap:62
CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js:sourcemap:6
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.umd.min.js:sourcemap:113
window.app.window.app @ (index):42
(anonymous) @ (index):44
```

What am I doing wrong?

Bonus points if this can be solved using AOT (i.e. *not paying the cost of JIT at runtime*).

Comment: Why do you need to use it in plain js? Is IE11 the reason?

Comment: @Ludwig I have edited my question and added more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sitting on this for a few days, I've managed to achieve what I want. Basically, I was overthinking things.

[Here's the working Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/RhqTMEd7sov1hsuQroed?p=preview)

Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.5.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.18/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.5.5/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@5.1.0/bundles/core.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/common@5.1.0/bundles/common.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@5.1.0/bundles/compiler.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser@5.1.0/bundles/platform-browser.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@5.1.0/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/http@5.1.0/bundles/http.umd.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <!-- AppComponent -->
    <script>
      var AppComponent = function () { };

      AppComponent.annotations = [
        new ng.core.Component({
          selector: 'app',
          template: '<h1>Hello World!' + ' | VERSION: ' + ng.core.VERSION.full + '</h1>'
        })
      ];
    </script>

    <!-- AppModule -->
    <script>
      var AppModule = function () { };

      AppModule.annotations = [
        new ng.core.NgModule({
          imports: [ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule],
          declarations: [AppComponent],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
      ];
    </script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Angular -->
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        ng.core.enableProdMode();
        ng.platformBrowserDynamic
          .platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
      });
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Highlights:

- `AppModule` and `AppComponent` are just JavaScript objects, with a simple Angular annotation. It would be very easy to add regular functions onto them.
- I did not need to use a `.Class` function.
- The bootstrap code is simpler, and actually quite obvious now.

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

In the console, it says *ng.core.Class is not a function* for the version you are using.

Change the scripts references in your **index.html** :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js@2.4.1/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.21/dist/zone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@2.1.2/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/common@2.1.2/bundles/common.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/compiler@2.1.2/bundles/compiler.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser@2.1.2/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.2/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/http@2.1.2/bundles/http.umd.js"></script>
```

And here is the **app.module.js**

```
(function(app) {
  var NgModule = ng.core.NgModule;
  var BrowserModule = ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule;
  var AppComponent = app.AppComponent;

  app.AppModule = NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() { }
  });
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! While this certainly works, I need to use Angular 4+. Perhaps this fluent API  has changed - will keep digging.